# Delphi TRichEdit Bullets are being formatted as fullstops

Tags: delphi, rtf

When formatted text is pasted from MSWord to a TRichEdit control, the bullets are well formatted (on the display) but after;

1. Fetching the rtf data from the TRichEdit control using TStringStream,
2. Saving the stream's DataString to a database and then
3. Loading the saved rtf string back to the TRichEdit control

The bullets are being formatted as fullstops

Using Delphi 7, Windows xp, msftedit.dll for RichEdit

Please assist

Comment: You forgot to include an important fact so we can't answer this question in it's current state. Please specify the database engine and the field type you are storing the RTF in...

Comment: The database is MSSQL, field is in VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Confusing wording (to me). Are the bullets formatted as full stops or are you losing all rich formatting? Did you try saving the TStringStream to a temporary RTF file? Open it up into Notepad and see if still contains RTF. If you can read the file it doesn't contain RTF.

Comment: We can't answer this unless you show the precise code you use to round-trip the RTF between the control and the DB.

Answer (score 1):

After much checking, found that the issue was being caused by a change in the font before saving, but I still cannot understand why the text is well formatted if the rtf is set to charset = ANSI_Charset but becomes distorted the moment I change the font name to "Times New Roman"

Comment: For further reading http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-web-character-encoding/